# When considering an inequality such as $x+\sin x \cos x \ge x-1$ why is it sufficient to only prove that x-1 goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

Conceptually, I understand that if

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x-1 = \infty$$

and if $x-1 \leq x + \sin x \cos x$, then  it must follow that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x + \sin x \cos x = \infty$$

I believe this due to the squeeze theorem, but doesn't that require it to be both bounded below and above?

Edit: Would it be correct to assume that knowing $\sin x\cos x \in [-1,1]$ that $x-1 \le x + \sin x\cos x \le x+1$ so by squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x \to \infty}x + \sin x\cos x = \infty$

Comment: First start with the definition of what it means to say the limit is $\infty.$

Comment: A function with limit $+\infty$ cannot be bounded above.

Comment: If $~\infty~$ was a finite number, which it **is not**, then your analysis would be nice.  However, $~\infty~$ is simply a **symbol** of unbounded growth.  The *syntax* of $~\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty~$ is simply **syntactic sugar** for writing that $~f(x)~$ grows unbounded in such a way that given any positive integer $~M,~$ there exists a real number $~y~$ such that $~\forall x \geq y,~$ you have that $~f(x) > M.~$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a little cumbersome to solve this issue with the squeeze theorem/sandwich lemma and depending on your formulation of the theorem it may even be a little problematic as it may require your limit to live in a certain intervall, which is not true for $\infty$.
However there is a similar statement for functions diverging to $\infty$. In particular we have the following.

**Lemma.** Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}f(x)=\infty$ and $g(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then we have $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(x)=\infty$.

For recollection-purposes we should start with the definition of the limit to $\infty$ of some given function. Usually for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ this is defined as follows. In the case that the limit is some real number $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we define
$$\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}f(x)=a:\Leftrightarrow\underset{\epsilon>0}{\forall}\ \ \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}}{\exists}\ \ \underset{x\geq X}{\forall}\ \ |f(x)-a|<\epsilon$$
In the case that the limit is $\infty$ we usually have the following definition
$$\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}f(x)=\infty:\Leftrightarrow\underset{C\in\mathbb{R}}{\forall}\ \ \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}}{\exists}\ \ \underset{x\geq X}{\forall}\ \ f(x)>C$$

If we want to prove that $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}x-1=\infty$ we therefore have to show that $\underset{C\in\mathbb{R}}{\forall}\ \ \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}}{\exists}\ \ \underset{x\geq X}{\forall}\ \ x-1>C$.
Therefor let $C\in\mathbb{R}$. We define $X:= C+2$. Then for all $x\geq X$ we have
$$x-1\geq X-1=C+2-1=C+1>C.$$
Thus we have shown that $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}x-1=\infty$.

If we now want to prove that $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}x+\text{sin}\ x\ \text{cos}\ x=\infty$, we can show this directly as above as follows.
Lt $C\in\mathbb{R}$. We define $X:= C+2$. Then for all $x\geq X$ we have
$$x+\underbrace{\text{sin}\ x\ \text{cos}\ x}_{\in\left[-1,1\right]}\geq x-1\geq X-1=C+2-1=C+1>C$$
Thus we have shown that $\underset{C\in\mathbb{R}}{\forall}\ \ \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}}{\exists}\ \ \underset{x\geq X}{\forall}\ \ x+\text{sin}\ x\ \text{cos}\ x>C$ and hence that $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}x+\text{sin}\ x\ \text{cos}\ x=\infty$.

However observe that to do so we used the inequality $x+\text{sin}\ x\ \text{cos}\ x\geq x-1$ leading to the idea to generalize this approach for any $g,f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ by defining $X$ for $g$ in the same way as for $f$. More precisely we can prove with this idea the Lemma abvoe as follows.

*proof of Lemma.* We want to show that
$$\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(x)=\infty:\Leftrightarrow \underset{C\in\mathbb{R}}{\forall}\ \ \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}}{\exists}\ \ \underset{x\geq X}{\forall}\ \ g(x)>C$$
Therefor let $C\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}f(x)=\infty$ there exists some $X\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\geq C$ for all $x\geq X$. But then we also have that $g(x)\geq f(x)\geq C$ for all $x\geq X$. Hence we have shown that $\underset{C\in\mathbb{R}}{\forall}\ \ \underset{X\in\mathbb{R}}{\exists}\ \ \underset{x\geq X}{\forall}\ \ g(x)>C$ and thus $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(x)=\infty$.